# Explanation on derivation of angle from isosceles triangle

Tags: geometry, triangles, angle

**Problem and diagram:**
[static system](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x8f6Y.png)

**Problematic approach:**
*"To write the balances, we will also need to determine the angle which the stick makes to the horizontal line, which is $\phi = \frac{β−α}{2}$ (this can be retrieved by carefully drawing the triangles involved)."*

**Question:**
How the $\phi$ angle was derived?

Comment: Hint: what is the angle sum for a triangle?

Comment: Angle sum is 180 degrees, but I'm not sure how that helps derive `φ`

Comment: Use some facts about parallel lines (alternate interior angles).

Comment: Managed to solve it, thanks for the hints - should I post the solution or diagram to answer this question? or just flag it as answered?

Comment: This is a physics problem which can be solved by canceling two torques. If you have the angles $\alpha$ and $\beta$ to start with, then the angle $\phi$ is completely irrelevant to finding the ratio of the masses as far as I can see.